# How to remove an element from LinkedList in stable Rust?

Tags: rust, linked-list

I have a linked list of values and I want to remove elements from there either by value or by index. I tried to use the remove function, but the compiler says that this function is not stable. Is it possible to remove elements from an arbitrary location in a linked list using only stable Rust?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the array using [`split_off`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.LinkedList.html#method.split_off) then join them back together without the element. See [this comment on github](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/69210#issuecomment-647864685)

> ```rs
> // Split the list in 2
> let split_list = original_list.split_off(index_to_remove);
> // Remove the first element of the second half
> split_list.pop_front();
> // Join the 2 halves back together, except for the middle element
> original_list.append(split_list);
> ```